# What's the R equivalent of Stata's _n function?

Tags: r, stata, lag, equivalent, lead

I am wondering whether there is a function in R like in Stata, where you are able to use the value of the observation n numbers before or after each observation. For instance if I need to multiply or divide with the observation before I would write something like this `variable_x/variable_x[_n-1]`

Comment: `variable_x/lag(variable_x, 1)`

Comment: @Khashaa `variable_x/dplyr::lag(variable_x, 1)`

Comment: Strictly `_n` is not a function at all. It's a built-in variable that is the current observation number, current meaning in the present `sort` order of the dataset. There is an extra twist in that under the aegis of `by` _varlist_:  that is determined within the current group defined by the combinations of distinct values of _varlist_. (I don't expect this to be fully self-explanatory to R users who don't use Stata any more than a brief definition of some R syntax would typically be in reverse.)

Comment: In R, dataframes can be indexed with `1:nrow(df)` and vectors can be indexed by `seq_along(vec)`. The explanation about a `by` _varlist_ raises the possibility of a homology with the R `by` function where the _varlist_ equivalent would be `list(factor1, factor2, ...)`. I have found the Stata documentation rather opaque, but have also heard the same complaint about R documentation from Stata adherents. There is a different mindset needed for the two languages. The types of objects are precisely listed in the docs but those type-names don't always line up with the _naive_ expectations of users.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you can't get the exact same functionality. For example, in Stata, you might iterate with _n like...

```
clear
set obs 5
gen x = 1
replace x = x[ _n - 1 ]*1.1 if _n > 1
list 

     +--------+
     |      x |
     |--------|
  1. |      1 |
  2. |    1.1 |
  3. |   1.21 |
  4. |  1.331 |
  5. | 1.4641 |
     +--------+
```

In R, you can handle this case with the `cumprod` function. In other cases, you can use `cumsum`. And in others, `lag` (as mentioned by @Khashaa). These solutions cover most but not all cases.

If you really need to iterate using the prior row and can't use one of these shortcuts, you can still use a loop (with R syntax being similar to Stata's). If the loop is slow, you can also write it in C++ with the Rcpp package.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what the phrase "n numbers before" actually means. If it is an index then I may have interpreted it incorrectly. You can get the last value calculated with the semi-hidden `.Last.value` variable:

```
> for( i in 1:10) x <- x*.Last.value
> x
[1] 177147

> 3^11
[1] 177147
```

If you are using an index `i` to refer to an item, `obj` then obviously you could refer to `obj[`i-10`]`. There is an embed function that constructs a matrix of columns that are "shifted".

```
x <- 1:10
embed (x, 3)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    3    2    1
[2,]    4    3    2
[3,]    5    4    3
[4,]    6    5    4
[5,]    7    6    5
[6,]    8    7    6
[7,]    9    8    7
[8,]   10    9    8
```

Answer (score 0):

The shortest way is:

bysort vect:gen n=_n

```
vect=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4)
n=ave(1:length(vect), vect, FUN = seq_along)
```

bysort vect:gen N=_N

```
ave(1:length(vect), vect, FUN = length)
```